# Javascript radio button check does not work using columns

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a table in which I have one form per tablerow,each form has three radio buttons,I would like to get the radioButton's value and store it in an array.Getting an alert from inside the switch case in this function does not work:

```
 var registerEventToRadio = function registerEventToRadio(formName, radioName, radio) {
//alert('aaaa'); works uncommenting this causes 9 alerts...
var mandyEvent = function mandyEvent(event) {
    switch (formName) {
        case 'rowform_chandelier':
            mandatoryArr[0] = 1;
            alert(1); //does not work
            break;
        case 'rowform_fireplace':
            mandatoryArr[1] = 1;
            alert(1); //does not work
            break;
        case 'rowform_rooflights':
            mandatoryArr[2] = 1;
            alert(1); //does not work
            break;
    }
};

var viEvent = function viEvent(event) {
    switch (formName) {
        case 'rowform_chandelier':
            visibleArr[0] = 1;
            alert(1); //does not work
            break;
        case 'rowform_fireplace':
            visibleArr[1] = 1;
            alert(1); //does not work
            break;
        case 'rowform_rooflights':
            visibleArr[2] = 1;
            alert(1); //does not work
            break;
    }
};

var renoEvent = function renEvent(event) {
    switch (formName) {
        case 'rowform_chandelier':
            renameArr[0] = 1;
            alert(1); //does not work
            break;
        case 'rowform_fireplace':
            renameArr[1] = 1;
            alert(1); //does not work
            break;
        case 'rowform_rooflights':
            renameArr[2] = 1;
            alert(1); //does not work
            break;
    }
};
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
    if (radioName === 'mandatory') radio[i].onclick = mandyEvent;
    if (radioName === 'visible') radio[i].onclick = viEvent;
    if (radioName === 'rename') radio[i].onclick = renoEvent;
}
```

};

This function is called in this manner:

```
var reno = getRadioButtonArray(formName, 'rename');
registerEventToRadio(formName, 'mandatory', mandy);
registerEventToRadio(formName, 'visible', vi);
registerEventToRadio(formName, 'rename', reno);
```

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsiampolu/2wMCZ/13/) is a JSFiddle which consists of all the code used there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getRadioButtonArray` returns a single radio element, not an array, so your code doesn't do anything because you are trying to iterate through a non-array. Changing the `for` loop to this will get the events to run:

```
if (radioName === 'mandatory') radio.onclick = mandyEvent;
if (radioName === 'visible') radio.onclick = viEvent;
if (radioName === 'rename') radio.onclick = renoEvent;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2wMCZ/15/

FYI - Placing a `<form>` directly inside a `<tr>` is not valid HTML.

Comment: Can I place a tr inside a form?

Comment: No, a `tr` can only go inside a `table`, `thead`, `tbody`, or `tfoot`. I suggest that rather than relying on forms that don't do anything, you identify the relevant items by ID. On the other hand, it is possible to get your functionality to work even with invalid HTML.

Comment: What about using `this.value` instead of 1 in the `switch-case` statements.Would they get the value of the radio button?